# Enable bitlocker does nothing

Tags: windows-10, bitlocker

I'm using Windows 10 Pro for workstation 20H2 and I'm trying to encrypt my C drive.

I've tried with the right click on drive and "Enable Bitlocker", I follow the procedure (I only want to use TPM without password), and at the there are 2 options :

- I keep hardware check : it does nothing. Even if I reboot
- I skip hardware check : a window appears to tell me the **decryption** is in progress

With Powershell I get the same results.

If I go to Settings/Device Encryption, I click on "Turn On" and I get an error : "Something went wrong. Try again later".

The computer is a DELL Precision 7550 freshly installed and up to date.

The TPM is available and ready and I've already tried to reset it, but BitLocker still doesn't want to encrypt the C: drive.

Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: So you have enabled and take ownership of the TPM in BIOS? When Bitlocker activation fails check Windows event log for errors/warnings.

Comment: If your PC has a TPM 2.0 make sure your Windows is installed and uses UEFI mode. According to [Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/security/information-protection/tpm/trusted-platform-module-overview) it will not work in BIOS/CSM mode.

Comment: Yes TPM is enable, I see it in tpm.msc and it's ready to use. My Windows is in UEFI mode. There are absolutly no logs in the event manager.

Comment: Then I would try to enable Bitlocker using `manage-bde` command-line. May be you are getting at least an error message to start with on the reason why it always fails.

Comment: Same. manage-bde says it encrypt the drive, but a manage-bde -status says the decryption is in progress. No more errors or warnings.